# Git on Bitbucket: Always asked for password even after uploading my public SSH key

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a number of codebases that I hack on locally and push to a remote repo private repo on bitbucket in order to keep backed up.

Today I started a new project and created a repo on bitbucket to push it to.

However, every time I try to do a push, I'm asked for my username and password on bitbucket.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: May you share an example of the git repo url you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you originally cloned the repository through HTTPS, and therefore the "remote" you are referencing is still set to the original `https://...` URL. You will have to update it to use SSH.

List the remotes with `git remote -v` (there usually is only one remote called `origin`, except special configurations), then use `git remote set-url` to update them:

```sh
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:<USER>/<REPO>.git
```

This is also mentioned in the Bitbucket documentation [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository/).

Next time you `git clone` a repository, you can directly use the SSH URL version (in the above form), so that the remote will be set up to use SSH.

Comment: Thanks. Editing the remote url in .git/config worked. The only thing worth adding is that I didn't clone the repo via https. I created it both on local and on bitbucket before pushing from local. This detail might be relevant to anyone finding this via google.